# Searching a dictionairy with an array as key?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, search

I was wondering if it was possible to have a dictionairy, where the key is an array of strings, and then search through the dictionairy by comparing a search term with the array?

EG:

my array has 7 words in it

That array is the key. I want to search the dictionary for any key/value where the key might contain the word 'has'. Is this possible?

Comment: and what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that basically won't work - even with a custom equality comparer. It sounds like what you *really* want is a dictionary of individual words, where each individual entry has multiple values. You can create that pretty easily using [`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx), if you've got the input data as a sequence already.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Dictionary with custom comparer could be the way to go (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx), but in your sample (Array contains a word), there could be more results matching one key. So Dictionary is probably not the best storage to choose, beacuse it will return only one value

Answer (score 0):

I would go with linq to transform the collection of words (the key) with their value to a dictionary with as key a word and as value an array of all the values that have a key containing that word, exactly.

```
public class WordsWithValue
{
    public string[] Words { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public IDictionary<string, object[]> GetValuesForWord(IEnumerable<WordsWithValue> wordsWithValues)
{
    return wordsWithValues.SelectMany(wwv => wwv.Words.Select(word => Tuple.Create(word, wwv.Value)))
                            .GroupBy(tuple => tuple.Item1, tuple => tuple.Item2, (word, values) => Tuple.Create(word, values.ToArray()))
                            .ToDictionary(tuple => tuple.Item1, tuple => tuple.Item2);
}
```

You can of course rewrite this in a few more methods to make this more clear, another option is to use anonymous classes instead of the `Tuple`s I used here to have more sensible names than `Item1` and `Item2`.